# List by most common in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am new here so sorry if my question isn't as good as you may be used to.
Put basically I have an MySQL database with multiple columns such as "name", "description" and "tags".
If my user searched for a specific word such as "apple", how would I go through all of the columns and return the rows in the order of most common to least common.
An example would be: the user searches for "apple" and the first result with that will show at the top of the list (as my current system does) however "banana" has more occurrences of apple in the  description and tags so I want that to be at the top.
I really hope this makes sense and thanks for any help!
EDIT: So apparently this is too broad so put very simply. 3 columns (name, description, tags). Lets say there a 3 rows, with names: apple, banana, grape.
If my user searches for apple I DO NOT want apple to appear at the top of the results as it is in the database itself. I want to check all 3 columns and list them in order of total occurrences. Such as if grape has 20 occurrences and banana has 17 and apple has 3 then the search results would be listed in order: grape, banana, apple.
What I currently have is: `"SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%$result%'"`

Comment: Nope, don't get it can you publish some sample date?

Comment: When a user is searching `apple`, is that a `name`?

Answer (score 1):

You could just count it using the built in count function in mysql

The following example counts the amount of times " UserId " have been used but you can modify it to your need.

[Mysql COUNT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html)

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(*)
FROM badges
GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```